# How to Resize a window based on size of customView in COCOA (OS X)?

Tags: cocoa, resize, nsview, nswindow

I am very new to Apple applications development, I make any mistakes in asking these question try to forgive me.

Actually I am having a Window of size 350 X 470, in these window I am having one customView.
In these custom view I want to load three different Views(.xib's).

- 1st View of size 250 X 300
- 2nd View of size 478 X 406
- 3rd View of size 565 X 600

I am using

```
[[_viewController view] removeFromSuperview];
_viewController = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyXibName" bundle:nil];
[_customView addSubview:[_viewController view]];
```

Every thing like switching from one view to another view and closing particular views are working fine, but resizing window according to view size is not occurring.

I referred many sites and few lines of code regarding these, but I haven't get any solution for these from any one of those.

It would be pleasure if any one helps me in achieving these.
If possible please give me answer for 'passing values from one view to another view' also.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically you have to call the method `setContentSize:` on your window and pass the size of the view to be embedded in that window.

```
 _viewController = [[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyXibName" bundle:nil];
[yourWindow setContentSize:FVC.view.frame.size];
[_customView addSubview:FVC.view];
```

This is in case your _customView take all the content space of your window.

Comment: will any please suggest whats the type of FVC and how I can provide sizes for that FVC.

Comment: fvc = firstViewController; ( or any other NSViewController instance),

Comment: These is working fine but it is not viewing my view fully.
Actually I want to display these view by extending my window's width. Let us think that my window.frame.size.width is 145, for these 145 how can I add my view width.

Comment: Ya I got the solution for that, by adding size in NSSize object as
NSSize userWindowNewSize;
    userWindowNewSize.height=235;
    userWindowNewSize.width=_viewController.view.frame.size.width+145;
    
    [self.window setContentSize:userWindowNewSize];